# GitHub: Using UTF-8 encoding for files

Tags: git, encoding, github

**Why isn't UTF-8 the default encoding for GitHub?**

Does that mean that there are **any drawbacks to change from the default "cp1252"**?

Does it have anything to do with using GitHub across platforms between Windows and Mac OSX?

The question is asked from using GitHub, but can be asked about **Git in general**.

*I'm mostly doing development in .NET, HTML5 and Javascript, if that matters in the subject.*

Comment: What does github care about encoding of your content?

Comment: Can you please point out where exactly you're seeing a default encoding?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I don't want to check in a file from my Mac OSX and find it with squares and broken characters on my Windows-machine. Or vice versa.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt According to "Git GUI" in Windows it say what I stated: "cp1252".

Comment: @Seb Nilsson: It's not the job of git to ensure you're using encodings correctly. And I think the setting in git is only relevant if you do interactive merging

Comment: Some version control tools have metadata that stores the file encoding.  Git is not one of them.

Comment: @EdwardThomson This statement is not very accurate. Take a look at [gitattributes](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html), in concrete you can tune how some tools will handle encoding by setting [`encoding`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_viewing_files_in_gui_tools) (I haven't tested it though)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wild guess: are you using TortoiseGit? Is that were you're seeing a default encoding set to cp1252?

If so, it's simply TortoiseGit using the default encoding of your Windows installation.

**Edit:** Exactly the same is true for the Git GUI

Here's a [discussion from a git developer's mailing list](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-GIT-GUI-GITK-0-8-Encoding-support-in-GUI-td1096529.html) giving an explanation:

> - Make diffs and blame default to the system (locale)   encoding instead of hard-coding UTF-8.
> - Add a gui.encoding option to allow overriding it.
> - gitattributes still have the final word.
>
> The rationale for this is Windows support:
>
> 1. Windows people are accustomed to using legacy encodings    for text
>      files. For many of them defaulting to utf-8    will be
>      counter-intuitive.
> 2. Windows doesn't support utf-8 locales, and
>      switching    the system encoding is a real pain. Thus the option.

Comment: Dude, what took you so long? Now I know, it's perfectly explained and I can find it when Googling it. With history behind the decision and not simply a "just ignore it and move on", that isn't constructive. Thanks

Comment: Hi Michael, can you edit your answer. How do I solve it? what are the step I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: @Shiro: you can set the encoding globally using git-config, or per path using gitattributes. Refer to the manpages for those commands for details.