# git+dropbox, 2 platforms - Windows 7 and Mac OSX 10.8.3

Tags: git

I start with a opencart project in Mac OSX.

I use GitHub client to commit to repo. I had committed few times, got 6-7 commit records.

My source code is store inside dropbox.

I also got another workstation which is working in Windows. I have sync all the file in Windows.

In Windows, I used TortoiseGIT. In the Windows Explorer, it shows exactly the same like same Mac, which means what file I edit before it shows red exclamation mark. File didn't amend, it got a green tick.

However, in Windows when I select GIT Commit to Master, it shows all my files are modified. I go to Command Prompt check with git status, it also showed all the file is modified.

When the modified file (actual modified file) dropbox sync with Mac OSX, in Mac OSX, I can track the real modified file. Mac OSX work perfect.

But it is not work well in Windows.

What actually goes wrong?

[image: Windows Explorer Display]

[Windows 7] Windows Explorer View

[image: Command Prompt Display]

[Windows 7] Command Prompt View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably related to differing line endings.
See [this Github article](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) for details and instructions on how to clean up the repository.

Comment: I check with the git diff, the file is showed identical. I believe the line ending is the same. If the line endings is diff. In Windows Explorer they will not display a tick there.

Comment: In my experience, differing line endings can show exactly that behaviour you are describing.

Comment: I tried, set the git config --global core.autocrlf true, it still asking me to commit the file. I more positive to encoding issue. Thanks!

Comment: If the project is already checked out, changing the autocrlf isn't enough because the checked-out files will have the wrong line endings. Did you also reset the repo (Described under "Re-normalizing a repository" in the article above)?

Comment: Thank for the 're-normalizing' step, i did in the mac and windows platform. Now should be work normally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is normal. It is a encoding problem between mac and windows. I had that too a few times. I think you first worked on mac and created the whole project there? So all the files are mac encoded..
Maybe this question and the answers could help you further: [GitHub: Using UTF-8 encoding for files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038729/github-using-utf-8-encoding-for-files)

Comment: I got many project also work between Mac and Windows. However, this is the first time I commit at Mac, which have this problem. Other initial created in Windows does not have this issue with Mac.

Comment: In this case, how can I 'fix' this problem in Windows? Please advice. Thanks!